# iPhone+want tapku libarary calender cell color

Tags: iphone

I'm using tapku library for displaying a calender in my application  I have done all of the date calculations and amrked the cells properly according to my need, but I want to give diff diff color to the cell according to my choices.

Please help me, I have to solve this issue as early as possible..

Comment: The tapku library uses four images, name begin with "Month Calendar Date Tile", to show each day cell in the month calendar view. If this is what you are looking for, you may check the "- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect" in "TKCalendarMonthView.m" of TapkuLibrary.xcodeproj.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the images used by Tapku Library.

```
    self.selectedImageView.image = [UIImage      imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today Selected Tile.png")];
```

(That code was from "TKCalendarView.m")

The images are found at: "TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today" or you could make the path point to one of your own images.